# Grub menu taking too long to appear

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, mbr

I am using Windows 10, Ubuntu and Debian 10 in my machine. Everything was fine untill some Debian update (or so as I think).
Now when i restart my system only a underscore is displayed on my screen for 2-4 minutes and then the grub list of OSs appears.

I thought something was wrong with my HDD so i booted in windows and installed EasyBCD and wrote the windows MBR over grub, then the system booted perfectly without delay when Windows bootloader took over. Again i booted in Debian using Windows bootloader(EasyBCD), same underscore appeared but this time with following message.

```
GRUB4DOS 0.4.6a 2018-11-05 root is (0x80,0)
Processing the preset-menu...
 (hd0,4)
  [Multiboot-kludge, loadaddr=0x10000, text-and-data=0x6591, bss=0x0, entry=0x10098c]
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Following are some outputs that might help,

```
root@providence:~# systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 17.873s (kernel) + 36.640s (userspace) = 54.514s 
graphical.target reached after 36.623s in userspace
```

Note that Windows 10 is installed in /dev/sda3 and Debian 10 is installed in /dev/sda8, where as the stupid /dev/sda1 is Windows System Reserved.

```
root@providence:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST9500420AS     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc8000000

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 170128349 169921502    81G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       170144408 337927335 167782928    80G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       337927336 976771071 638843736 304.6G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       337927338 459016191 121088854  57.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       459018240 467015679   7997440   3.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       467017728 856739009 389721282 185.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       856739840 976771071 120031232  57.2G 83 Linux
```

PS: I got mad and removed Ubuntu. Poor ubuntu.

What can i do to resolve this before i format everything. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up removing Ubuntu, formatting windows system reserved, removing grub, installing Lilo, removing Lilo, removing debian, deleting partitions, moving partitions, reinstalling debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

After everything i booted into windows and saw something, that's when it clicked me.

Basically, when i saw windows was booting perfectly and grub was delaying, it implied that my HDD and BIOS were absolutely fine. Also my GRUB was fine too because i literally installed another OS with new grub and all.

The fault lied in my boot order. My CD/DVD drive is jammed and somehow was reading a disk. So whenever system boots, it'll try to read DVD first for few minutes then it'll jump to HDD.

I removed CD/DVD drive. Case closed.